# Apply rotation to a point in QML

Tags: qml

How to rotate a point using `rotation` property from another item?
I want to draw a line from (0 0) to a top left corner of a Rectangle

```
Rectangle {
    id: "rect"
    color: "blue"
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 70
    height: 150
    rotation: 30
    transformOrigin: Item.BottomRight
}

Shape {
    ShapePath {
        strokeColor: "red"
        startX: 0
        startY: 0
        PathLine {x: rect.x; y: rect.y}
    }
}
```

Getting this:

[image: line to rect]

Comment: you cannot rotate point, it's just pointless, sorry for the tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to draw a line to the `Rectangle`'s local point. In this case you can recalculate the local point from item's coordinate to some scene/parent/some item coordinates using [Item.mapTo*()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method-1) functions. The `mapTo` takes `transforms` into account so rect.offset will change during rotation in the following example:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Shapes

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        property int angle: 0
        property point offset: Qt.point(100, 0) // top left local point
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "orange"
        antialiasing: true
        smooth: true
        transform: Rotation { origin.x: 100; origin.y: 100; angle: rect.angle }
        PropertyAnimation on angle {
            from: 0
            to: 360
            duration: 5000
            loops: Animation.Infinite
        }

        onAngleChanged: {
            var p = rect.mapToItem(line, rect.offset); // maps offset from rect's coordinates to the line's ones
            line.link = p;
        }
    }

    Shape {
        id: line
        property point link: Qt.point(0, 0)
        antialiasing: true
        smooth: true
        ShapePath {
            strokeColor: "green"
            strokeWidth: 5
            capStyle: ShapePath.RoundCap
            startX: 0
            startY: 0
            PathLine { x: line.link.x; y: line.link.y }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `offset` probably should be `(0, 0)`. i.e. `property point offset: Qt.point(0, 0) // top left local point`

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of @folibis answer that uses property binding for `mapToItem`.

```
    property point link: (rect.rotation,
                          rect.mapToItem(line, rect.corner))
```

I added `rect.rotation` as a dependency to the formula so that it will trigger a reevaluation every time the `rotation` changes, however, the actual `rect.rotation` value is discarded since we use `rect.mapToItem` to perform the actual evaluation.

Here's a fully working example. I also added 4 RadioButton for each corner respectively, so that you can change which corner the red line is drawn to.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Shapes
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: palette.buttonText }
    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        color: "blue"
        x: 200
        y: 200
        width: 70
        height: 150
        rotation: slider.value
        transformOrigin: Item.BottomRight
        property var corners: [
            Qt.point(0,0),
            Qt.point(rect.width,0),
            Qt.point(0,rect.height),
            Qt.point(rect.width,rect.height)
        ]
        property int cornerIndex: 0
        property point corner: rect.corners[rect.cornerIndex]
        Repeater {
            model: rect.corners
            RadioButton {
                x: modelData.x - width / 2
                y: modelData.y - height / 2
                checked: index === rect.cornerIndex
                onToggled: if (checked) rect.cornerIndex = index;
            }
        }
    }
    Shape {
        id: line
        property point link: (rect.rotation,rect.mapToItem(line, rect.corner))
        ShapePath {
            strokeColor: "red"
            startX: 0
            startY: 0
            PathLine {x: line.link.x; y: line.link.y}
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: palette.button }
        RowLayout {
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            Label { text: "Rotation" } 
            Slider {
                id: slider
                from: 0
                to: 360
                value: 30
            }
            Label { text: slider.value.toFixed(1) }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment! Having an update based on rect.rotation changes indeed very useful!